# How to check logs for Rails application on Unicorn and Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, unicorn

I'm facing issue with one part of application which doesn't exist when I run application from production environment on localhost but there are no logs presented in `/log` folder.

Application is running on DigitalOcean with Debian 8 droplet.

Answer (score 1):

Open `config/environments/production.rb` file and change

`config.log_level = :info`

to

`config.log_level = :debug`

Too set `config.consider_all_requests_local` to `true` to get full error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the nginx logs on your development environment on Mac OS X, and you installed nginx with homebrew, the logs will be located at `/usr/local/var/log/nginx`.